# Will my calendar and contacts in iCloud be lost if I delete backups?

Tags: icloud, backup, contacts, calendar, storage

I cannot do any new backups because my iCloud storage is full.

I want to switch to using my computer for backups and delete the ones I have in iCloud. However I don’t want to lose my contacts and calendar that are also stored in iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete your backup from iCloud. To do this, go into **Settings** →  **Your Profile** →  **iCloud** →  **iCloud Backup** and turn the switch to `Off` to disable iCloud Backups.

This will only delete your *iPhone backup* from iCloud. It will **NOT** delete your iCloud contacts and calendars.

Comment: Should contacts and calendars somehow be lost, they can be restored in the Settings of your iCloud.com account.